# Dynamics CRM 2011: Disable pop-up that comes after Xrm.Page.ui.close();

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

How to disable pop-up ("There are unsaved changes in this window...") that comes after calling  `Xrm.Page.ui.close()`?

I'm calling this function straight after `Xrm.Page.data.entity.save()` so all the fields are saved before closing the form.

The solution to `setSubmitMode("never")` does not work:

```
var attributes = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get();
    for ( var i in attributes){
        attributes[i].setSubmitMode("never");
    }
Xrm.Page.ui.close();
```

Comment: How are you calling `close` "straight after" `save`?

Comment: Just one statement after another, like this: `Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
 Xrm.Page.ui.close();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `saveandclose` parameter:

```js
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save("saveandclose");
```

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334720.aspx#BKMK_save):

> save("saveandclose")
>
> Save and Close button in the ribbon. This is the equivalent of the user clicking the Save and Close button in the ribbon.